# How do I remove an attribute with an invalid name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I need to remove an attribute with an invalid name from a link that I don't have access to at the moment, but still need to change.

Until I can get to the code I am using jQuery to change the element's `href` attribute and remove some unnecessary attributes:

```
jQuery(".description p a").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("href", "https://newsite.com/pricelist");
    jQuery(this).attr("title", "Have a look at our new pricelist");
    jQuery(this).removeAttr("attr1 attr2 attr3"); //eight attribute in total
});
```

This works as exptected.

However, the `a` element also contains a ninth (empty) attribute with an invalid name, namely `n&#039;` (including the semi-colon). I don't know how it got there, but I need to get rid of it.

When I add `n&#039;` to the list of removable attributes in the above code the browser console states `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'n&#039;' is not a valid attribute name`, which I understand. However, when I escape the `&`, `#` and `;` characters (`n\&\#039\;`) the console shows the exact same error.

I know that `&#039;` is the HTML-code representing the quote character (`'`). I have dabbled with `html_entity_decode`, but can't seem to get it right.

How do I get rid of this invalidly named attribute using jQuery?

Comment: It looks like the error is in setAttribute.. try to search for unclosed quotes / singlequotes in the dom?

Comment: I checked and can't find any unclosed quotes. By the way: am not using setAttribute anywhere, only removeAttr.

The remaining code in the dom after execution of the code is: `<a href="https://newsite.com/pricelist" title="Have a look at our new pricelist" n&#039;="">the complete list</a>`.

Comment: `Failed to execute 'setAttribute'` is the un-wrapped equivalent jQuery(this).attr(), ..try to remove that as first instruction inside the .each(), before to set new ones

Comment: The simple way works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/15o6dbt0/. Are you sure you've provided the right starting HTML? Why does it even matter if this attribute is there?

Comment: Thanks for your time by the way! I don't quite understand what you mean. I am not setting any new attributes. I am just changing the values of `href` and `title` and removing all other attributes. What exactly do you suggest for me to change?

Comment: @thirtydot You are right, of course: it doesn't really matter if the attribute is there. I'd just like to have clean code. In your JSFiddle you gave `n&#039;` a value of `f`. In my code it's just empty. But even if I leave it empty in your code, the attribute is removed. In my code it isn't... Anyway, although I'm curious why it behaves this way, I'll leave it at that. Thanks to you both. I appreciate your time and efforts!